How do I update my Crucial MX500 firmware to M3CR046?
I am trying to update the firmware of my Crucial MX500. I have followed the instructions in the installation guide, but booting the firmware ISO only displays an error:

I have tried burning it to a CD and a USB drive. I tried booting it from two different computers and a VM but always get the same error. I tried copying the /boot folder to every subdirectory on the ISO but grub still can't find it.
I also tried booting the CD and ISO with both UEFI and legacy boot.
